# Loading HTML data in mysql table

Tags: html, mysql

how can i load html data in one of my mysql fields.

I can make this work if the table has only HTML column.

load data local infile '/tmp/htmlas.txt' 
into table HTMLDATAPRINCE
lines terminated by ''
(htmldata1);

What delimiter should i use when i have many columns and html column in one of the columns in it.lines terminated by \n doesn;t work well with HTML code.

Comment: *HTML column*? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` doesn't parse HTML. You'll need to write something to do that yourself.